# moveTo and moving documents from one library to another

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have followed and successfully implemented the excellent article:

SharePoint 2010 ECMAscript – Copy\Move files to another document library – Part 2

located at:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/28/sharepoint-2010-ecmascript-copymove-files-to-another-document-library-part-2/

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
    Id="CopyingFilesButton"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
    RegistrationId="101"
    RegistrationType="List"
    Sequence="5"
    Title="Copy Documents">
        <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
                <CommandUIDefinition
                Location="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.Controls._children">
                    <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.Manage.CopyDocuments"
                    Command="CopyDocumentsButtonCommand"
                    LabelText="Move To Supplier Invoices"
                    Image32by32="/_layouts/images/MoveToSupplierInvoices/multiplemovebutton.png"
                TemplateAlias="o1" />"
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler
            Command="CopyDocumentsButtonCommand"
            CommandAction="javascript:
                var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var web = context.get_web();
                context.load(web);
                var _destinationlib = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Shared Documents');
                context.load(_destinationlib);
                var notifyId;
                var currentlibid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
                var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentlibid);
                var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
                var count = CountDictionary(selectedItems);
                for(var i in selectedItems)
                {
                    alert('Now moving ' + i);
                    var currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
                    context.load(currentItem);
                    var File = currentItem.get_file();
                    context.load(File);
                    //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to get the loaded values
                    context.executeQueryAsync
                        (
                            function (sender, args) {
                                if(File != null) {
                                    var _destinationlibUrl =  web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + _destinationlib.get_title() + '/' +  File.get_name();
                                    alert('Now moving to: ' + _destinationlibUrl);
                                    File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
                                    notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file ' + File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);
                                    //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to copy the file
                                    context.executeQueryAsync(
                                        function (sender, args) {
                                            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                                            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File moved successfully', false);
                                        },
                                        function (sender, args) {
                                            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error moving file: ' + args.get_message(), false);
                                            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                                            showError(args.get_message());
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            function (sender, args) {
                                alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
                            }
                        );
                }"/>
        </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

I wanted to change the code to move the documents so I changed the line:

```
File.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
```

to:

```
File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
```

(see above) hoping that would work.

Unfortunately, I get the error 'input string was not in a correct format'.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Walter

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested the the File with move, but from the documentation its a flag not a boolean:

```
SP.File.moveTo(newUrl, flags) 
flags
Specifies the kind of move operation.
It must not have flags other than MoveOperations.Overwrite or MoveOperations.AllowBrokenThickets set.
Type: SP.MoveOperations


SP.File.copyTo(strNewUrl, bOverWrite)
bOverWrite
Specifies whether a file with the same name is overwritten.
Type: Boolean
```

The different types from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658974.aspx):

```
none
overwrite
allowBrokenThickets
bypassApprovePermission
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert('Now moving to: ' + _destinationlibUrl);                                        
File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl,1);
```

It worked for me.