# ECMAScript moveTo move document to another web in same site

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have studied and used the following post to attempt to move a document:
[moveTo and moving documents from one library to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33043/moveto-and-moving-documents-from-one-library-to-another)

This works perfectly when moving documents to different libraries in the same web or even folders in the same library but I am trying to move a document to a different library in the parentweb.

1. Is this possible?
2. How can I do it?

So far I have changed the code to this which is returning error 0x002 "Illegal Argument Exception":

```
            //current web is "/web/sub/";
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var site = context.get_site();
            var dst = "/web/lib/fold/";
            var dstweburl = dst;
            dst += "myfile.txt";
            var destweb = site.openWeb(dstweburl.substring(0,dstweburl.substring(0, dstweburl.length-1).lastIndexOf("/")+1));
            var destfold = destweb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(dstweburl);
            context.load(destfold);

            var web = context.get_web();
            context.load(web);

            var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(unescape(ListGUID));
            var currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(ItemID);
            context.load(currentItem);
            var File = currentItem.get_file();
            context.load(File);
            //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to get the loaded values
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function(sender, args){
                    if(File!= null){
                        if(moveFlag){
                            File.moveTo(dst, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
                        }
                        else{
                            File.copyTo(dst,true);
                        }
                        //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to copy the file
                        context.executeQueryAsync(
                            function (sender, args) {
                                $("<div>Item moved/copied successfully.</div>").appendTo("#response");
                            },
                            function (sender, args) {
                                $("<div>Error moving/copying item. 0x002</div>").appendTo("#response");
                            }
                         );
                    }
                    else{
                        $("<div>Error moving/copying item. 0x001</div>").appendTo("#response");
                    }

                },
                function(sender, args){
                    $("<div>Error moving/copying item. 0x000</div>").appendTo("#response");
                }
            );
```

Comment: `SP.File.moveTo` function only supports moving documents within the same site. It will not allow you to move files to other sites.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande when you say in the same "site" are you refering to site collection or web?

Comment: I meant web. Sorry for the confusion. You cannot move a document to another web within the same SiteCollection with `SP.File.moveTo`

Comment: Take a look at Mikael Svenson's article. He has explained how to move/copy file between different sites using REST. Though the code he has uses AppContext, you should be able to do it without App. http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

Comment: @Aveenav his post is regarding SP 2013. I am on SP 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have instead used the SPServices JS library.
Code for moving with the metadata is here: [Copy document from one site to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another)