# How do I move files from one document library to another using JSOM?

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, move

I have two document libraries on the same web, and am wanting to move the files from one to the other using JSOM/CSOM.

Can anyone please shed some light on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help with this, though for my use case the answer was a bit more simple. Here is the code I used to move files from one document library to another (on the same web)

```
function moveFiles(sourceLib, destLib){

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourceLib);
context.load(folderSrc,'Files');
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        console.log("Got the source folder right here!");
        var files = folderSrc.get_files();
        var e = files.getEnumerator();
        var dest = []; //Just to check it got the file path right
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            var file = e.get_current();
            var destLibUrl = destLib + "/" + file.get_name();
            dest.push(destLibUrl); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
            file.moveTo(destLibUrl, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
        }
        console.log(dest); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log("Files moved successfully!");}, function(sender, args) {console.log("error: ") + args.get_message()});
        }, 
    function(sender, args){console.log("Sorry, something messed up: " + args.get_message());}
    );
```

}

```
//Usage:
var srcLibrary = 'Temp Library';
var destLibrary = 'Pages';

moveFiles(srcLibrary, destLibrary);
```

Comment: Can I get the file object after move operation(after file moved successfully)? Want to refresh some fields for this file..

Answer (score 4):

Use following code to copy documents :

```
public static void CopyDocuments(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string srcLibrary, string destLibrary, Login _login)
    {
        // set up the src client
        SP.ClientContext srcContext = new SP.ClientContext(srcUrl);
        srcContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
        srcContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new SP.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(_login.UserName, _login.Password);

        // set up the destination context (in your case there is no needs to create a new context, because it would be the same library!!!!)
        SP.ClientContext destContext = new SP.ClientContext(destUrl);
        destContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
        destContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new SP.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(_login.UserName, _login.Password);

        // get the list and items
        SP.Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
        SP.List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(srcLibrary);
        SP.ListItemCollection col = srcList.GetItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
        srcContext.Load(col);
        srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // get the new list
        SP.Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
        destContext.Load(destWeb);
        destContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var doc in col)
        {
            try
            {
                if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.File)
                {
                    // get the file
                    SP.File f = doc.File;
                    srcContext.Load(f);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // build new location url
                    string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + f.Name;

                    // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                    SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
                } 

                if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
                {
                    // load the folder
                    srcContext.Load(doc);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // get the folder data, get the file collection in the folder
                    SP.Folder folder = srcWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(doc.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                    SP.FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;

                    // load everyting so we can access it
                    srcContext.Load(folder);
                    srcContext.Load(fileCol);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (SP.File f in fileCol)
                    {
                        // load the file
                        srcContext.Load(f);
                        srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        string[] parts = null;
                        string id = null;

                        if (srcLibrary == "My Files")
                        {
                            // these are doc sets
                            parts = f.ServerRelativeUrl.Split('/');
                            id = parts[parts.Length - 2];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            id = folder.Name;
                        }

                        // build new location url
                        string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + id + "/" + f.Name;

                        // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                        SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log("File Error = " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

For jaavscript you can use SPServices JS library. Code for moving with the metadata is here: [Copy document from one site to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another)

For more details:

http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2012/08/22/sharepoint-2010-using-the-client-object-model-to-move-files-and-folders-across-site-collections-and-subsites/

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm not very familiar with C# (CSOM) and also realise that there are a few methods that are not available to JSOM. Anyone generous enough to translate this into JS? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer with javascript code. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another

Comment: You should not supposed to modify the Document Library name: destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") should be destLibrary. It works now.