# Object doesn't support property or method 'getFolderByServerRelativeURL'

Tags: 2013

I am trying to move a file from one folder to another on my SharePoint 2013 server. I tried using the answer with 5 upvotes on this link: [How do I move files from one document library to another using JSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-do-i-move-files-from-one-document-library-to-another-using-jsom?newreg=a05104f04749481e94bc0480f0ff951b).

But, when the script hits `var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourceLib);`, an error message appears in the console:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'getFolderByServerRelativeURL'`

I'm guessing `web` was not properly loaded. What do I need to do to load `web` correctly?

Comment: can you paste you whole code? where are you running this in document.ready?

Comment: I am unable to paste the code for reasons. This function is ran within a button's click() method call in document.ready.

Comment: It seems that your context and web object is not intialized

Comment: Could you post at least part of the code, modifying what you don't what us to see? More specifically, how are you getting this web variable and what are you doing with it before this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run your code under this

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    

      //write code here to get web object and then server relative url 

});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you everyone for your help!