# Copy document to another site

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, document

Does anyone know how to recreate the functionality of the "SendTo another location" option in SharePoint?

It looks like CopyTo only allows to copy documents within the same site.

If possible I would also like to keep the link between the files as the Send To functionality does.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this just once or setup with a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a workflow along with the custom activities add-on which is available free at code plex. That will help you to move/copy the items cross the sites.

- [Copy List Item Extended Activity](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home) - Allows copying/moving list items
  and files cross site.
  This works for the SharePoint 2010.

Also check this solution, which may help you. [Copy document from one site to another..?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another)