# App, read file from another web - always Unauthorized. How to get another context?

Tags: jsom, app

I am trying to read file from another web. But I always get 'Unauthorized', even if permissions for my "AppManifest.xml" are 'Full control' for site collection. Tried to use SP.AppContextSite constructor but don't understand how to implement it: it says 'appContext.load is not a function' or other different erorrs

```
// read file, MS example
function readFileMS() {
    var anotherWebUrl = "http://server/web/subweb/";
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    // cannot get it to work..
    var otherContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, anotherWebUrl);
    var otherWeb = otherContext.get_web();

    // If uncomment here I get 'otherContext.load is not a function'
    //otherContext.load(otherWeb);

    // try query context of second web
    // If I change from 'clientContext' to 'otherContext' I get 'otherContext.executeQueryAsync is not a function' error
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        // I can get this file in browser. Permissions for app are "Full control" for site coollection,
        // but it does not work
        var fileUrl = "http://server/web/subweb/Shared Documents1/TextFile1.txt";
        $.ajax({
            url: fileUrl,
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function () {
            console.log("The content of file 'TextFile1.txt' is: " + data);
        }).error(onFail);

        console.log("Queried another Context");

    }, onFail);
}
function onFail() {
    console.log("Error: " + arguments[2]);
}
```

if I do 'clientContext.executeQueryAsync' - I get 'Unauthorized'.

I try to implement examples from here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
but in my case I want to query different web in same site collection.

**Update**: Thank You Sam! Tried Your code, but it is till unauthorized oO. Think I need use REST webservices for this task..

p.s.: got "sp proxywebrequestexecutorfactory is not a constructor" so I loaded SP.Scriptexecutor before my script:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    var layoutsfolder = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load SP.RequestExecutor.js first
    jQuery.getScript(layoutsfolder + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
        console.log("SP.RequestExecutor is now loaded");

        initializePage();
    });
}, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code instead of your code.

```
// read file, MS example
function readFileMS() {
    var anotherWebUrl = "http://server/web/subweb/";
       var otherContext= new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var factory =
                new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(
                    _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                );
            otherContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
           var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(otherContext, anotherWebUrl);
var otherWeb = appContextSite.get_web();

    // If uncomment here I get 'otherContext.load is not a function'
    otherContext.load(otherWeb);

    // try query context of second web
    // If I change from 'clientContext' to 'otherContext' I get 'otherContext.executeQueryAsync is not a function' error
    otherContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

        // I can get this file in browser. Permissions for app are "Full control" for site coollection,
        // but it does not work
        var fileUrl = "http://server/web/subweb/Shared Documents1/TextFile1.txt";
        $.ajax({
            url: fileUrl,
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function () {
            console.log("The content of file 'TextFile1.txt' is: " + data);
        }).error(onFail);

        console.log("Queried another Context");

    }, onFail);
}
function onFail() {
    console.log("Error: " + arguments[2]);
}
```

Above code is use for cross domain call context.

Comment: Thank You for answer Sam! I'll try on Monday and write back here!

Comment: Okie try and let me know if you face any difficulties

Comment: Thank You Sam! Unfortunately doesn't work for me( Updated post. Think I need to use REST there..

Comment: Found that for example function "file.copyTo" works only for current web, we need to use rest to copy from one web to another. Maybe same problem here

Comment: Yes, file.copyTo function have limitation. It will copy file in same web. If you want CSOM code for move file then let me know i have.

Comment: Hi Sam! Resolved, used example with SPServices from here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another Thank You twice!

Comment: Okie welcome Gennady